# Can you add attributes to an object dynamically?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to create an object then add attributes to the object on the fly. Here's some pseudocode EX1:

```
a = object()
a.attr1 = 123
a.attr2 = '123'
a.attr3 = [1,2,3]
```

EX2: [the first page of this PDF](http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-002-introduction-to-matlab-spring-2008/other-matlab-resources-at-mit/tutorial07.pdf)

In Python is it possible to add attributes to an object on the fly (similar to the two examples I gave)? If yes, how?

Comment: You haven't created an object; you've simply created another name for the built-in type `object`.

Comment: @chepner I never specified if the above EX1 is real python code or pseudocode. Given your comment I will clarify and state that the above code is pseudocode and therefore I was only trying to convey the idea. --- I also updated the pseudocode. Hopefully the edit is more clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Python 3.3+, use [types.SimpleNamespace](http://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html):

```
>>> import types
>>> a = types.SimpleNamespace()
>>> a.attr1 = 123
>>> a.attr2 = '123'
>>> a.attr3 = [1,2,3]
>>> a.attr1
123
>>> a.attr2
'123'
>>> a.attr3
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I like this answer because it solves the question without needing a custom class.

Comment: For other readers I recommend @roippi 's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234753/can-you-add-attributes-to-an-object-dynamically/18235205#18235205) because it has a good explanation on how Python language/objects behave with dictionaries.

Answer (score 4):

> In Python is it possible to add attributes to an object on the fly
>   (similar to the two examples I gave)?

Yes.

> If yes, how?

You could do:

```
class AttrHolder:
    pass

a = AttrHolder()

a.attr1 = 123
a.attr2 = '123'
a.attr3 = [1,2,3]
```

Or even something truly awful like:

```
import email #my choice of module is arbitrary

email.random_attribute = 'hello'
```

The unasked question: should you be doing this?  Probably not.  You're just using these things as stand-ins for a proper `dict`.  If you want named attributes, consider a `namedtuple`.

```
A = namedtuple('Attribute_Holder',['attr1','attr2','attr3'])
a = A(123,'123',[1,2,3])
```

This provides a (loose) contract for `A`, and gives a nice `repr`:

```
In [70]: print(a)
Attribute_Holder(attr1=123, attr2='123', attr3=[1, 2, 3])
```

Or just use a `dict`.  That's what they're for.

In fact, that's what you're doing when you 'add attributes on the fly', just with an unnecessary layer of abstraction.  Consider, using the above `AttrHolder`:

```
In [77]: a = AttrHolder()

In [78]: a.__dict__
Out[78]: {}

In [79]: a.hi = 'hello'

In [80]: a.__dict__
Out[80]: {'hi': 'hello'}
```

You're using a `dict` whether you like it or not!

Comment: In the Matlab community, creating new attributes is common in code and is seen as a beneficial practice when used in certain situations (see Example 2 that I gave in the question). I'm not an expert on Python's language/library/community/etc and so I would be interested to hear from expert Python devs: which is better in Python creating attributes on the fly or using a dictionary? If it isn't clear which is better, which method is more common? Generally how much more common is one over the other?

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith using a `dict` is preferable, because that's what you're doing anyway.  See my edit.

Comment: re - "You're using a dict whether you like it or not!" wow! that is really great demonstration/proof showing that you are using a dict anyway. I'll have to read more about the \_\_dict\_\_ in Python documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
class Test:
    pass
for mark, name in enumerate(("attr1", "attr2", "attr3")):
    setattr(Test, name, mark)
print Test.attr1
print Test.attr2
print Test.attr3
```

output:

```
0
1
2
```

So, the answer is "yes".  Although it might not be such a good idea (could lead to problems such as losing track of the attributes or something).

Comment: Strictly speaking, you can add attributes dynamically to objects which have a `__dict__` attribute, something lacking in instances of most (all?) built-in types such as `object`, `int`, etc.

Comment: @chepner - I understand your point.  But are you sure he means the `object` built-in, or any object such as a class?  He wasn't very clear.

Comment: I was trying `a = object()` and other built-in types because that was the most simple example code to come up with. If you are telling me that the limitation is present in most/all built-in types then I will know I can do this as long as I am not using a built-in type.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith - Oh, I thought you meant an object like a class.  You can only do what I did on objects that have a `__dict__` method.  The `object` built-in does not.  One way to see if a specific object has a `__dict__` method is to do `dir(object)` where object is your object.

Comment: I ran your example code. The class `Test` implicitly inherits from `object` which doesn't have `__dict__` but the class `Test` does have `__dict__` when you do `dir(Test)`. Why does `class Test` have `__dict__` but `class object` doesn't have `__dict__`?

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith - That is a very good question and I'm afraid I don't really know the answer. If I had to guess, Python specifically blocked `object`'s `__dict__` method (as well as the other bult-in's `__dict__` methods) to keep you from altering the built-in.  Also, remember that the built-ins, though they are classes, are a little different from normal classes.  Some come strait from the underlying C code.  Thus, they operate slightly different then a normal class.

Comment: It's not that the `__dict__` attribute on `object` is blocked; it simply doesn't exist.

Comment: @chepner - Ah, thank you.  I said I didn't really know.  I always went by "Because that's the way it is" in that area. ;)

Comment: This is actually what *falsetru* recommends in the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18234825/1346705 here. The doc http://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace says: *Unlike object, with SimpleNamespace you can add and remove attributes.*

Answer (score 0):

Um, am I missing something?  Take the following example:

```
class C():
   def __init__(self, x):
       self.myX = x

c = C(42)
c.attr1 = 123
print c.myX
print c.attr1
```

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I use dictionaries for the exact purpose that you are describing (at least from my understanding of the question)...

```
dict = {}
dict["attr1"] = 123
dict["attr2"] = '123'
dict["attr3"] = [1,2,3]

dict.get("attr1")
```

Comment: ... or you could just use `dict.get()`

Comment: Wow, thank you. Fixed to use `dict.get()` instead. I actually didnt know `get()` would handle that for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to add attributes to an *anonymous instances* of an *anonymous class*, you could write:

```
>>> obj = type('obj', (), {})()
>>> obj.attr1 = 123
>>> obj.attr2 = '123'
>>> obj.attr3 = [1,2,3]
```

But, really, don't do this!